# Как правильно оформить предложение и расставить запятые?

Tags: синтаксис

Если больной не обратится к врачу и не будет следить за своим здоровьем, то это может привести к инвалидности и даже к смерти из-за болезней, возникших вследствие ревматического полиартрита.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, предложение составлено верно, знаки препинания тоже правильно стоят. Единственное добавление: вставить слово "вовремя" после "больной" и исправить опечатку в слове "возникших"

Answer (score 0):

Если больной не обратится к врачу и не будет следить за своим здоровьем, то это может привести к инвалидности и даже к смерти из-за болезней, возникших вследствие ревматического полиартрита.
Мне кажется, что всё верно с точки зрения пунктуации, но возникает один вопрос по поводу слова "возникших". Это действительное причастие ПРОШЕДШЕГО времени. Если болезни УЖЕ возникли, его можно оставить. А если болезни только МОГУТ ещё возникнуть, то лучше употребить оборот "которые могут возникнуть". таким образом, окончательный вариант может выглядеть так. 
Если больной не обратится к врачу и не будет следить за своим здоровьем, то это может привести к инвалидности и даже к смерти из-за болезней, которые могут возникнуть вследствие ревматического полиартрита.